# Node Webkit - Finding standard directories

Tags: node-webkit, program-files

Is it possible to find standard directories like 'Program Files' or 'Windows' and their Linux and Mac equivalents in Node webkit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for that:

```
process.env[(process.platform == 'win32') ? 'USERPROFILE' : 'HOME']
```